Как через Overpass API получить id автобусной остановки в формате gtfs
Суть такая, на телефоне я отображаю карту Open street map с помощью либы osmdroid, через Overpass API я получаю автобусные остановки в заданном bbox, мне нужно по клику на автобусную остановку получить id остановки в формате, который используется в gtfs, те id которые возвращаются через Overpass API не подходят. Пишут что есть такой ключ gtfs:stop_id
 [out:json];
    node["public_transport"="platform"]["gtfs:stop_id"](59.914676, 30.313811,59.929195,30.375996); 
     out body;

Но он не работает у меня, всегда возвращается пустой список. Помогите кто может .
